# RIGHT JOIN or UNION with MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, join, union

I have a table:

```
+----+--------+-------+
| ID | Winner | Loser |
+----+--------+-------+
|  1 |      1 |     4 |
|  5 |      1 |     2 |
|  6 |      1 |     3 |
|  3 |      2 |     3 |
|  4 |      2 |     4 |
|  2 |      3 |     4 |
+----+--------+-------+
```

Winner and loser are both ITEM ID's from another table.

I'm trying to achieve a query that returns the columns: 
ITEM ID, CountWinners, CountLosers.

The purpose being, for each itemID, that item will have wonX games and lostY games. If there as a tie of wins, I can sort by losses

```
SELECT t1.ID, t1.WinnerCount, t2.ID, t2.LoserCount from
(Select winner as ID, count(winner) as WinnerCount from rp_poss group by winner) as t1
FULL OUTER JOIN
(Select loser as ID, count(loser) as LoserCount from rp_poss group by loser) as t2
ON t1.ID=t2.ID
```

Which returns:

```
+------+-------------+----+------------+
|  ID  | WinnerCount | ID | LoserCount |
+------+-------------+----+------------+
| 2    | 2           |  2 |          1 |
| 3    | 1           |  3 |          2 |
| NULL | NULL        |  4 |          3 |
+------+-------------+----+------------+
```

Rather than

```
+----+-------------+------------+
| ID | WinnerCount | LoserCount |
+----+-------------+------------+
|  1 |           3 | 0          |
|  2 |           2 | 1          |
|  3 |           1 | 2          |
|  4 |           0 | 3          |
+----+-------------+------------+
```

I've tried using UNION ALL but cannot get it to work. Any ideas?

Comment: Columns are a bit confusing - the `ID` column in your table at the top is not actually used in your output? ( I am seeing aggregate groups for winner/loser, but no relationship to `ID`)

Comment: @michaelberkowski he means the people represented by the integers in winner/loser

Answer (score 0):

```
select t_all.id, 
 coalesce(WinnerCount,0) WinnerCount, 
 coalesce(LoserCount,0) LoserCount
from (select distinct winner id from mytable
union select distinct loser id from mytable) t_all
left join (select winner, count(*) WinnerCount
    from mytable group by winner) winners on t_all.id = winners.winner
left join (select loser, count(*) LoserCount
    from mytable group by loser) losers on t_all.id = losers.loser
order by WinnerCount, LoserCount
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use a union like so (with conditional aggregation):

**Fiddle:** http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/27ef6/3/0

```
select person as id,
       sum(case when result = 'W' then 1 else 0 end) as winnercount,
       sum(case when result = 'L' then 1 else 0 end) as losercount
  from (select winner as person, 'W' as result
          from rp_poss
        union all
        select loser, 'L'
          from rp_poss) x
group by person
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you mention that you have another table with `IDs` I would use it in my solution

```
SELECT t1.id, COUNT(w.id), COUNT(l.id) 
FROM TableOfIDs t
LEFT JOIN YourTable w ON t.id = w.id
LEFT JOIN YourTable l ON i.id = l.id
GROUP BY t1.id
```

This way you can simplify your query.

If the *other* table has more IDs than in your Winner/Looser table than we can eliminate unnecessary zeroes with a `HAVING` clause.

```
HAVING COUNT(w.id)+COUNT(i.id) > 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
SELECT ID ,Coalesce(Winners,0),Coalesce(Loosers,0)
FROM (
        SELECT ID , 
                    ( SELECT Count(Winner) FROM rp_poss WHERE WINNER=A.ID GROUP BY Winner ) Winners,
                    ( SELECT Count(Looser) FROM rp_poss WHERE Looser=A.ID GROUP BY Looser ) Loosers                     
        FROM rp_poss A
) result
WHERE Winners > 0 OR Loosers > 0
```